# What is the difference between Viva connections and Microsoft teams app

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

What is the difference between Viva connections and Microsoft teams app. Both Viva connections and Microsoft teams seem to be the same there is nothing much difference between the two. Could someone help me out to know the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, there are two main differences:

1. When you generate the app using the Viva Connections PowerShell script, there's an extra property added to the manifest that isn't supported in, for example, App Studio - the `searchUrl` property. This is what makes the "Search" capability get added to the top Search box in Teams for the user (see some more info on my blog post: https://hilton.giesenow.com/2021-04-12-viva-connections-custom-search)
2. When you click the Viva Connections app icon in the Teams left menu for the first time, it takes the user to the Viva Connections app. When you click the icon *again*, it launches the Global Nav - I don't think will happen for a "normal" embed-a-sharepoint-page-in-teams app.